# Beer bottle leftovers pour quickly only after waiting?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, surface-tension

Why is it that after pouring a delicious beer from a bottle, I can hold it upside down for several seconds without reward, but if I wait a bit, the remainder presumably settles at the bottom and immediately pours out on demand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simply down to surface tension - a very small amount of beer (in a relatively thin film) will adhere strongly to a glass as the percentage of bonds between the water and the glass is high.

As the drop size increases (up to a point) more and more of the bonds are internal increasing the strength of the drop and decreasing the adhesion to the glass.

Comment: Is it not more about foam bubbles collapsing, than small drops joining into larger ones?

Comment: @Jaime I think we need a grant to study this one.

Comment: wouldn't it be viscosity?